# sharing an object between multiple applications in Delphi

Tags: delphi, ipc, shared-memory

I am trying figure out how to share an object between multiple applications in Delphi. I am aware that the way to do this is via IPC/windows shared memory calls (ie CreateFileMapping etc), however in all the example code I found they use a simple type like a string, whereas I need to share an object.

I'm wondering if it's even possible as I keep ending up with an application that just shares the pointer reference to the object but not the object memory itself. When I try to retrieve and then access the object from my other app I get an access violation. I think this because the pointer refers to protected memory from the other application.

Here is the code I have tried so far (as you can see I'm trying to share an TADOConnection object between multiple apps so that there is only one database connection used/shared between apps). If there there is a better/simpler way to do this (sharing an ADO connection) I'm interested to know how to do it.

```
  TSharedData = record
    Connection: TAdoConnection;
  end;

  PSharedData = ^TSharedData;

var
  SharedData: PSharedData;
  hFileMapping: THandle;  
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function CreateNamedFileMapping(const Name: String): THandle;
begin
  Result := CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, nil, PAGE_READWRITE, 0,
    SizeOf(TSharedData)*8, PChar(Name));

  if Result > 0 then
    SharedData := MapViewOfFile(Result, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0);
end;

function GetSharedData: PSharedData;
begin
  result := nil;
  hFileMapping := OpenFileMapping(FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, False, 'MySharedMemory');
  if (hFileMapping > 0) then
    Result := MapViewOfFile(hFileMapping, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0);
end;

procedure TForm1.createClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   hFileMapping := CreateNamedFileMapping('MySharedMemory');
   if (hFileMapping > 0) and Assigned(SharedData) then
   begin
     SharedData^.Connection := TAdoConnection.Create(nil);
     // can't use Assign as it is not supported by _Connection
     SharedData^.Connection.ConnectionObject := AdoConnection1.ConnectionObject;
   end;
end;

procedure TForm1.retrieveClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   SharedData := GetSharedData;
  if assigned(SharedData) then
    // should be set to true if everything was ok
    ShowMessage(BoolToStr( SharedData.Connection.Connected, true));
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
   AdoConnection1.Connected := False;

  if assigned(SharedData) then
    UnmapViewOfFile(SharedData);
  if hFileMapping > 0 then
    CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
end;


procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AdoConnection1.Connected := true;
end;

end.
```

ADOConnection1 is an object on my form. I am aware that I need to copy the entire object memory by using something like "Assign" however this doesn't exist on the ADO ConnectionObject. To make sure it's not just the ConnectionObject thats the problem I also tried passing a simple object like a TStringlist and then using assign to copy the memory but it still gets the AV in app #2.

If I run create and retrieve within the same app it works fine. When I take a copy of this application and run "create" function in app #1 and "retrieve" in app #2 I get the access violation.

Comment: Shared memory can't help. Tiered database access is what you need. Middle tier accesses the database and the clients talk to that middle tier rather direct to the DB.

Comment: It's impossible to share an object instance across process boundaries. IPC/shared memory/memory mapped files are not going to change it. In addition, even if you could do so, database connections are made on a per-thread basis, and the two processes are clearly not going to be executing in the same thread.

Comment: Why do you think you need to share the ADO connection?

Comment: Maybe You can use HOOKS mechanism to do something like that.

Comment: Why do you need to share the database connection?  That doesn't seem like a normal thing to either want or need to do.  What are you trying to achieve?  What problem will this solve for you?  Certainly this is not the correct approach.

Comment: `how to share an object between multiple applications` Microsoft DCOM (Distributed Component Object Model). Or cross-platform CORBA (Common Object Request Broker Architecture). Or SOAP (Simple (ha-ha) Object Access Protocol). Or..... anything invented in last 30+ years stating from UNIX wars :-D

Comment: @Arioch'The: None of which are Delphi objects, specifically a TADOConnection. IOW, your comment is not applicable to the question asked, any more than writing Tesla, Ferrari, and Lamborghini would be.

Comment: That depends upon semantics of "sharing object". It is the case of "what is your Z" most probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been established in the comments that it is not possible to share an object between different processes. I simplified your test case a bit to be able to clear why this is so.

In this version, the object that will fail to be shared is a much simpler one than an ADOConnection, one with only an integer field. The first instance of the application creates a mapping and writes a record having fields of an integer, an object and a string. Any subsequent instance of the application attempts to retrieve and display that information.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, System.SysUtils, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

type
  TSimpleObject = class(TObject)
  private
    FInt: Integer;
  end;

  TSharedData = record
    Int: Integer;
    SimpleObject: TSimpleObject;
    Str: string;
  end;
  PSharedData = ^TSharedData;

var
  SharedData: PSharedData;
  hFileMapping: THandle;

const
  MapName = 'MySharedMemory';

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  MapExists: Boolean;
begin
  hFileMapping := CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, nil, PAGE_READWRITE,
      0, SizeOf(TSharedData), MapName);
  Win32Check(hFileMapping <> 0);
  MapExists := GetLastError = ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS;

  SharedData := MapViewOfFile(hFileMapping, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0);
  Win32Check(SharedData <> nil);

  if MapExists then begin
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(SharedData.Int));
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(SharedData.SimpleObject.FInt));
    ShowMessage(SharedData.Str);
  end else begin
    SharedData.Int := 555;
    SharedData.SimpleObject := TSimpleObject.Create;
    SharedData.SimpleObject.FInt := 666;
    SharedData.Str := 'test string';
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Win32Check(CloseHandle(hFileMapping));
  Win32Check(UnmapViewOfFile(SharedData));
end;
```

The second instance of the application will be able to correctly show the first value, the integer field of the record. However it will fail with the integer field of the object or the string field of the record. It will either raise an access violation or display incorrect values.

I put a memo on the form and dumped some memory addresses to be able to see what's happening.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  MapExists: Boolean;
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
  hFileMapping := CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, nil, PAGE_READWRITE,
      0, SizeOf(TSharedData), MapName);
  Win32Check(hFileMapping <> 0);
  MapExists := GetLastError = ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS;

  SharedData := MapViewOfFile(hFileMapping, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, 0);
  Win32Check(SharedData <> nil);

  if MapExists then begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Found at %p', [SharedData]));
//    ShowMessage(IntToStr(SharedData.Int));
//    ShowMessage(IntToStr(SharedData.SimpleObject.FInt));
//    ShowMessage(SharedData.Str);
  end else begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Created at %p', [SharedData]));
    SharedData.Int := 555;
    SharedData.SimpleObject := TSimpleObject.Create;
    SharedData.SimpleObject.FInt := 666;
    SharedData.Str := 'test string';
  end;
  Memo1.Lines.Add('');
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('@SharedData.Int: %p', [@SharedData.Int]));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('PInteger(@SharedData.Int)^: %d', [PInteger(@SharedData.Int)^]));
  Memo1.Lines.Add('');
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('@SharedData.SimpleObject: %p', [@SharedData.SimpleObject]));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('@SharedData.SimpleObject.FInt: %p', [@SharedData.SimpleObject.FInt]));
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('PInteger(@SharedData.SimpleObject.FInt)^: %d', [PInteger(@SharedData.SimpleObject.FInt)^]));
  Memo1.Lines.Add('');
  Memo1.Lines.Add(Format('Pointer(@SharedData.Str)^: %p', [Pointer(Pointer(@SharedData.Str)^)]));
  Memo1.Lines.Add('character payload');
  Memo1.Lines.Add('PChar(Pointer(SharedData.Str)): ' + PChar(Pointer(SharedData.Str)));
end;
```

Below, on the left is the fist instance of the application, right one is the second instance. Note that the second instance might take a few attempts to show without an access violation.

[image]

The first line is the beginning address of the map. Note they are not the same in both instances (there's a possibility that they may be the same however). This is not of any concern for our case, but is the reason the [documentation of `MapViewOfFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366761(v=vs.85).aspx) warns:

> Do not store pointers in the memory mapped file; store offsets from
>   the base of the file mapping so that the mapping can be used at any
>   address.

The second line is the address of the integer field of the shared record. In both instances this is equal to the starting address of the mapped memory. This is expected as it's the first field of the record. The following line dumps the value that is hold in that address as integer, and they look fine.

The fourth line dumps the address of the object contained in the record. For both instances this is four bytes offset from the beginning of the map. Looks right? Continue with the following line which dumps the address of the integer field contained in the object.

There are two alarming things with the address of the integer field of the class. First, they are equal in both instances. This shouldn't be the case since the map files does not start at the same addresses at all. Second, they are way off of the address of the map file. After all we reserved 12 bytes, not 34 megabytes.

The reason for this is that, an object reference (having the address dumped in the preceding line) is actually a pointer to an object instance that lives elsewhere, and this pointer is pointing to a location outside of the mapped memory segment. This is not a problem for the first instance as it is the process that allocated the memory. For the second instance however, this address has a completely different meaning. Leave alone that there's no object in that address, there is a possibility that the address may not even be readable. It's no surprise that the dumped value as integer differs from the expected value.

The same explanation goes for the string field of the record dumped in the last paragraph. The address that the character string payload should be has a completely different meaning to the second process.

[`Assign`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TPersistent.Assign) will not help with the object field, it *copies properties and other attributes of the specified source object to the current object*, it doesn't relocate or copy an instance of an object. But one might wonder if it would be possible to create the object with instance memory defined on a known address, for instance by overriding `NewInstance`. Unfortunately this is also not possible for anything a little bit more complicated than the object in this example. It wouldn't be possible to contain all memory required for an object to function in a single block of memory. For instance for the ADOConnection you are trying to share, the `ConnectionObject` is yet another pointer.